# Rails 3 and apache and passenger on OSX - sqllite error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, apache, passenger

I am trying to deploy a Rails 3 app on OSX using Apache and Passenger.

The app runs well (in production mode using SQLLite) using Passenger from the command line

```
passenger start
```

but fails with the log as below when loaded from Apache.
I have tried gem pristine -all.

If I place index.html in the rails public folder it is displayed correctly.
Any help would be much appreciated

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2014-07-08 18:15:19 +1000

TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
  activerecord (3.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:26:in `initialize'
  activerecord (3.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:26:in `new'
  activerecord (3.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:26:in `sqlite3_connection'
  activerecord (3.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:309:in `new_connection'
  activerecord (3.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:319:in `checkout_new_connection'
  activerecord (3.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
  activerecord (3.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `loop'
  activerecord (3.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `block in checkout'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
...
```

The https.conf contains

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xxx.com.au
    ServerAlias www.xxx.com.au
    DocumentRoot /Users/xxx/Projects/wardround/public
    RailsEnv production
    RackEnv production
    <Directory /Users/cathy/Projects/wardround/public>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was an inconsistent management of ruby versions and associated gems.

Everything worked after
1. Using rvm to install and use a new ruby version

1. 'bundle install' to get the gems installed correctly.
2. Specifing the correct ruby in the apache configuration file as described at https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerRuby